# Interact with smart contract via tx offline signing - possible?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, myetherwallet, offline

In MyCrypto/MEW you can send an offline tx by signing it offline and broadcasting it online. Can I also somehow interact with a smart contract in the same manner (eg. the kyber network contract)?

Doesen't matter if I would have to do this via  MyCrypto/MEW or GETH, I just would like to know if there's a possiblity and how I can do it.

Comment: Future people who land here: you can find further discussion @ https://www.reddit.com/r/MyCrypto/comments/8deffh/interact_with_smart_contract_via_cold_storage/ & https://github.com/MyCryptoHQ/MyCrypto/issues/1495#issuecomment-381275053

Comment: This is my issue that I opened on github: https://github.com/MyCryptoHQ/MyCrypto/issues/1624

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you mean is if you can do an offline signing of contract transaction the answer is yes. Web3 gives the tools to do so. You can find the information [here](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-accounts.html)

Comment: Which steps do I have to perform in order to interact with for example the kybernetwork-contract offline?

Comment: I do not know what is kybernetwork, but interacting with contracts in ethereum shouldn't be dependent on who does it, you may want to make the question more specific and maybe make a new question because if difficult to answer using comments, let me know.